# Component did update behaving abnormally

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have implemented a block where i'm using `componentDidUpdate` to call a function if 2 of my condition meets the certain criteria. When both the condition satisfies it is calling the function which is then going to an infinite loop and executing the function for infinite times.

1. I have 2 drop-downs which are there to select the values. If both of them are having values, then call the function for this I'm using `componentDidUpdate` to keep an eye on changes on both the state variables.
2. When drop-down value change it will set the state to state variable which i'm using in the condition.

Below is my code:

```
 handleRegionChange(idx: any, event: any) {
    const region= [""];
    region[idx] = event.label;
    this.setState({ region});
  }

 handleProductChange(idx: any, event: any) {
    const productId= [""];
    productId[idx] = event.key;
    this.setState({ productId});
  }

componentDidUpdate() {
if (
  this.state.regionId?.[0] && this.state.productId?.[0]) {
  this.props.fetchValues(   // Redux action function which accepts 2 parameters
    this.state.regionId?.[0],
    this.state.productId?.[0]
  );
}}
```

Please help me in highlighting the issue or through some light on how to tackle or use component did update in this kind of situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's causing an infinite loop mostly likely because fetchValues will update your component props from it's parent, this triggers another update, which will run componentDidUpdate again.

One easy way to fix this is to prevent further update, if the id has not been changed for any dropdown values.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  const hasRegionIdChanged = this.state.regionId !== prevState.regionId;
  const hasProductIdChanged = this.state.productId !== prevState.productId;

  if (hasRegionIdChanged || hasProductIdChanged ) {
    this.props.fetchValues(
      this.state.regionId?.[0],
      this.state.productId?.[0]
    );
  }
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Further reading, see how React introduced the hook pattern to let you think of these things beforehand, requiring a dependencies list:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

2nd attempt:

```
// Not sure if this is a multi select dropdown,
// It should be either [] or a plain value

// Multi select dropdown
handleRegionChange(idx: any, event: any) {
  // You should not need to know which index is was, all you need is the region label ... (Updated for remove of duplication)
  // If you have access to the spread operator, then JSON.stringify is not required below
  const region = [...new Set([...this.state.region, event.label])];
  this.setState({ region});
}

// Single select dropdown
handleProductChange(idx: any, event: any) {
  this.setState({ productId: event.key});
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  // If it's an array/object, you need to compare them deeply
  const hasRegionIdChanged = JSON.stringify(this.state.regionId) !== JSON.stringify(prevState.regionId);
  const hasProductIdChanged = this.state.productId !== prevState.productId;

  if (hasRegionIdChanged || hasProductIdChanged ) {
    if (this.state.regionId?.length && this.state.productId) {
      this.props.fetchValues(
        this.state.regionId,
        this.state.productId
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @chris but the || condtion will not work in my case i want both the values to call the function. I have also tried the same thing but the prevstate is not getting updated when the one of the drop changes. For example : if i'm changing region id and then product id. The state of region id and prevstate region id both will have same values.

Comment: @Vin That sounds correct to me. Because there are 2 changes, first region id then product id. fetchValues will be called twice, first with a different region id and second with a different product id. 

The reason why we put || is because we want to see if any of those state changed. First dropdown select will make hasRegionIdChanged true and hasProductIdChanged false, the 2nd dropdown select will make hasRegionIdChanged false, hasProductIdChanged true.

I will try to refactor the solution, matching your intention better.

Comment: that's what I have mentioned, I need both the values to call the function and then call the function only once.

Comment: @Vin You will need to decide when this fetch will be called exactly once. A user can select any values in the 2 dropdowns with any order, upon detecting a valid combination, this will call the fetch method regardless. To make sure the user has finalised the selection, you will need a confirm button for fetching.